# Foiled by path-dependent types

Tags: scala, parser-combinators, path-dependent-type

I'm having trouble using, in one trait, a Parser returned from a method in another trait. The compiler complains of a type mismatch and it appears to me that the problem is due to the path-dependent class. I'm not sure how to get what I want.

```
trait Outerparser extends RegexParsers {

  def inner: Innerparser

  def quoted[T](something: Parser[T]) = "\"" ~> something <~ "\""
  def quotedNumber = quoted(inner.number)     // Compile error
  def quotedLocalNumber = quoted(number)      // Compiles just fine
  def number: Parser[Int] = ("""[1-9][0-9]*"""r) ^^ {str => str.toInt}

}

trait Innerparser extends RegexParsers {

  def number: Parser[Int] = ("""[1-9][0-9]*"""r) ^^ {str => str.toInt}

}
```

And the error:

```
[error] /Path/to/MyParser.scala:6: type mismatch
[error]  found   : minerals.Innerparser#Parser[Int]
[error]  required: Outerparser.this.Parser[?]
[error]   def quotedNumber = quoted(inner.number)
```

I sort-of get the idea: each "something" method is defining a Parser type whose path is specific to the enclosing class (Outerparser or Innerparser). The "quoted" method of Outerparser expects an an instance of type Outerparser.this.Parser but is getting Innerparser#Parser.

I like to be able to use quoted with a parser obtained from this class or some other class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-type annotation to make it compile while still preserving the modularity:

```
trait OuterParser extends RegexParsers { this: InnerParser =>
  def quoted[T](something: Parser[T]) = "\"" ~> something <~ "\""
  def quotedNumber = quoted(number)     // Compile error
}

trait InnerParser extends RegexParsers {
  def number: Parser[Int] = ("""[1-9][0-9]*"""r) ^^ {str => str.toInt}
}

object MyCompleteParser extends OuterParser with InnerParser
```

The self-type annotation basically says that OuterParser depends InnerParser  (they must be mixed together to create a proper instantiatable class). The compiler thus knows for sure that in OuterParser and InnerParser, `Parser` refers to the same type.

Answer (score 2):

For better or for worse, the way you usually use the Scala parser combinator libraries is to wrap everything in an enclosing trait or object that `extends` a trait like `RegexParsers`. I'm not quite sure why the API was designed like this.

But, anyway, once they all belong to the same instance of `RegexParsers`, they all see the same `Parser` type:

```
trait Everything extends RegexParsers {
    trait Outerparser {
        ...
    }

    trait Innerparser {
        ...
    }
}
```

And everyone is happy.

---

Don't think of it as putting everything in the same scope; think of it as the parser-combinator API's kooky way of importing names, ie, you could just as easily do

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
import scala.util.parsing.input._

object blah extends RegexParsers
import blah._

trait Outerparser {
    ...
}

trait Innerparser {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't want to put all my parsing code into the same scope like that. Any other ideas?